# Shallow copy of a collection in Java

Tags: java, list, collections, stack

For this method, I have to make a shallow copy of a linked list stack. 
So, first I would initialize the linked stack then would I use a for loop to go through the values to copy the stack. But, to put them in the right order, would I just have a nested loop to reverse the group of values? 
here is what I got so far, am I missing something? This will copy references of all the values in the stack to another stack.

```
LinkedStack<E> newStack = new LinkedStack<E>(); 
  for(int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++){   //objectCount is figuring out the count
     newStack.add[i] = newStack[i];
  // do I have to put a for loop here?
 return newStack; 
}
```

Comment: normally I don't ask this question, but is this a homework problem? if so you need to add the "homework" tag.

Comment: Well, there's no class called LinkedStack in the standard Java API, so I'm not really sure what you're asking about. Also, `newStack.add[i];` is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: i fixed it, so should I add a for loop???

Comment: `newStack.add[i] = newStack[i]`? The loop aside, how do you add something that you just initialized to it's own?

Comment: This code-example looks very strange. newStack.add[i] is only valid, if the LinkedStack class has a public array named add, but that would be very unusual. Additionally your for-loop has an opening brace, but no closing.

Answer (score 3):

If the stack in question is [this `LinkedStack`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/classes/doc/edu/cmu/cs/pattis/cs151xx/orderedCollections/LinkedStack.html), then, like most collections, it has a copy-constructor, and one that takes an array. I can't see from your code where is the original stack/array which you want to clone, but this is done easily via:

```
 LinkedStack<E> newStack = new LinkedStack<E>(originalStack);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use a LinkedList for your stack.

According to the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#clone()) , the .clone() method, but beware that elements in your stack won't be clone.