# Two level deep copy in Java

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy, shallow-copy

In Java, it's easy to deeply clone an object with [Object.clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) and also to shallow-clone (let's call it level 1).

How do you go about doing a [two-level deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248529/what-is-one-level-deep-copy-in-javascript), that is, copying all primitives, but also [creating (shallow) copies of all Object members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610544/shallow-copy-of-a-collection-in-java) ?

Let's say you copy a phone book with a list of number entries . A shallow copy would just

```
clone = original.getLNumberlist();
```

a deeper copy would do a

```
clone = new ArrayList<>(original.getNumberlist());
```

<sub>there are many questions about deep and shallow cloning, but I could not find any Java question about this two-level cloning, let alone its implementation</sub>

Comment: What's the difference in java between shallow-clone and one-level deep clone? I can't find a difference.

Comment: I think what you're describing is properly considered two-level, not one-level.  There's no good tool for it other than handwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for the naming and the answer @LouisWasserman

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer : amended with example

Comment: Do you want to clone every type of object or just a few specific classes?

Comment: @dan1st : cloning collections would be the primary use-case

Comment: Collections of what?

Comment: An Object cotaining java.util.Collections of mostly Hibernate Entities

Comment: @dan1st : please see reply above

Comment: what about creating a method in the object doing the cloning manually?